# current working directory in a vbscript invoked by a drag & drop operation

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, drag-and-drop, working-directory

When I was trying to get elevated rights for my batch script, when I found two related SO questions

- [How to request Administrator access inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894967/2932052)
- [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7044985/2932052)

...that led to answers that worked partially. For some reason, I had issues with command line passing for file path arguments containing spaces within the VBS script, so I tried to break the solution into 3 parts and concentrated on the inner (VBS) step, then adding the last step by calling a batch from that VBS which could not be found, despite in the same folder as the VBS script. I found that drag & drop isn't "that easy" *and* that it's different when using `.vbs` instead of `.bat` or `.exe` as drop targets.

## Here is my actual question:

If I drag a file and drop it onto an executable (exe) or batch file (bat, cmd), The current working directory is determined by the source of the dragged item. Its directory is set as the working directory for the program or script that processes it.

If I drop a file onto a VBS script, it's different. On Windows 8.1 x64 I observe it to be `C:\Windows\System32` even if the argument resides in the same folder as the VBS.

I can simply use a batch file (as drag'n'drop relay) like this

```
my.vbs %*
```

to get "the normal" `.bat` behaviour (drop source dictates CWD), but I also want to understand it.

Is it a bug or a feature? Is it consistent over all Windows versions?

---

**edit:** added the background (on top) for the question showing how I got there (+minor corrections)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some API monitoring, this is what I see

When you drop a file over a `.exe` file the `explorer.exe` uses [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function to start the process, passing the executable as `lpApplicationName`, and the executable and dropped file as `lpCommandLine`. The `lpCurrentDirectory` is set in the function call by the caller process to the folder containing the dropped file<sup>[1]</sup>.

When you drop a file over a `.cmd` file the `explorer.exe` also uses [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, but in this case the `lpApplicationName` is `null` and the `lplCommandLine` contains the batch file and the dropped file. `lpCurrentDirectory` is also set to the parent folder of the dropped file<sup>[1]</sup>.

When you drop a file over a `.vbs` file, [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used and the `lpDirectory` field of the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure is `null`, so, the process created inherits the current active directory of the parent process. By default the current active directory of the `explorer.exe` process is `%systemroot%\system32`, but it is possible to start a `explorer` instance with a different current active directory that will be inherited in this kind of drop operations.

<sup>[1]</sup> If we drop more than one file, the path of the file passed as first argument is used

**note** just for information: to test the active directory inherit the process followed was:

- Open a `cmd` instance and change the current active directory to `c:\temp`
- Kill all `explorer.exe` instances
- From the `cmd` instance call `explorer.exe`. This `explorer` instance has the active directory in the `cmd` window as its current active directory.

Comment: Impressive research! I just dropped a selection of two files from different folders (from search results) onto a bat file. I observed that the CWD of the script is set to the parent folder of the first argument, maybe worth to add to the *`set to the parent folder of the dropped file`* part of your answer.

Comment: @Wolf, I forget to include it, thank you. Answer updated.

Comment: I expect to see `CreateProcess` being used for `.bat` as well, and all other registered file types are just "opened" using `ShellExecuteEx`? Would you think it makes sense to search for a reference for the intended behaviour? Could this be a useful entry point: [Application Registration (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#related_topics)?

Comment: @Wolf, I don't know if there is even an "intended behaviour". It is documented (your link) the process to find an application, but not how it is started or even who starts it. It is entertaining to dig and see how it works, but I will not rely on it. It can change. For the case in this question, if the started process *depends* on what its active directory is, it is the script's responsability to ensure its environment is correct.

Comment: Well, maybe I better add this to the question: I was trying to figure out an error in a complicated batch+vbs combination step by step and this involved breaking a bigger script into parts, then it happened that I got an unexpected "file not found" error that I had to figure out next...

Comment: I think that's showing the (technical) reason best whereas [Ansgar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42057410/2932052) shows the way out.

Comment: In addition to an upvote, I want to say *Hell thanks*! You solved a mysterious problem with my vbs project (that processes files from command line).

Answer (score 2):

The [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s.aspx) property holds the full paths to all items dropped on the script, so you can determine the directory of each dropped item like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each item In WScript.Arguments
  WScript.Echo fso.GetParentFolderName(item)
Next
```

Assuming that the working directory would be defined by what is dropped onto a script is a misguided approach. If you require that logic you can implement it in the script yourself, though, e.g. like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For Each item In WScript.Arguments
  sh.CurrentDirectory = fso.GetParentFolderName(item)
  'working directory is now the parent folder of the current item

  '...
Next
```

If you need the working directory to be the parent directory of the VBScript file you can derive that from the [`ScriptFullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw.aspx) property:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance, and it makes (on the other hand) not so much sense, if I drop multiple targets, say from a search, onto a script to speak of the source directory...

Answer (score 2):

If I lookup the file types in the Windows registry, I see the following in their `Shell\Open\Command` values:

- batfile: `"%1" %*`
- cmdfile: `"%1" %*`
- exefile: `"%1" %*`
- VBSFile: `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`

This seems to suggest that `bat`, `cmd`, `exe` are *treated as executable* on their own, maybe for historical reasons, whereas VBS is considered an *ordinary script*, that is only executable because its extension is registered with some executable to be called to interpret it. Pretty much the same as Python or Perl.

**[Update]** Indeed I proved that a Python script shows exactly the same behaviour as my VBS script: calling it from the command line providing arguments keeps the CWD, dropping a file on it causes the CWD to be `C:\Windows\System32`. So my question seems to be sort of wrong, but finally it helped people to point me into the right direction for further research...

Answer (score 0):

`c:\windows\system32\CScript.exe` or `c:\windows\system32\Wscript.exe` are the programs that run vbscript. As you can see they are in `system32`.

Windows uses ShellExecuteEx to start programs - see it's rules at MSDN: 
[ShellExecuteEx function (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)

ShellExecuteEx uses CreateProcess (CreateProcessEx) to actually start a program. [CreateProcess function (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Edit**

CMD doesn't use the registry for it's own stuff. Those registry entries are for programs other than CMD.

CMD main goal is to be MS Dos 5 compatible while enhancing it, it will correctly run most DOS batch files. It was written by IBM engineers working on OS/2 NOT Windows.

**Edit 2**

The core of your problem is that you are attempting to write programs as if you are a user typing to operate a computer.

As a programmer you don't make assumptions. The easiest way to not take assumptions **is to specify full paths to what you want**. Your batch file shouldn't care what the current directory is. EG In CMD there is a current directory per drive for compatibility with MSDos 5 (and programs in a console tend to share them but don't have to). In Windows there is one current directory per program. The default current directory has changed over the years.

The only time you should work with the current directory is if you are writing a batchfile for a user to use. EG If you type `dir` it does the current directory, a batchfile meant to be a general command should work the same way.

Comment: Well, I expected something like this, but also `.bat` and `.cmd` scripts are executed by a command interpreted and this also resides in `system32` -- at least one of them ;-) -- Why the difference?

Comment: CMD does its own thing. CMD isn't even from Windows but OS/2.

Comment: Seems that would be the same for Python or Perl scripts..., isn't it that 
bat and cmd are built-in scripting capabilities in Windows since NT?

Comment: CMD pre-processes things.

Comment: you mean `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Yes. See CMD's behaviour here https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AAFjUcKneSZhDjw&id=E2F0CE17A268A4FA%21121&cid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA for **The Windows NT Command Shell Ch 1** which used to be available from MS web site.

Comment: It has nothing to do with where the interpreting script is stored, see [my results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42057809/2932052), but thanks anyway, you helped me to narrow down the actual question.